# How to use adb commands using java?

Tags: java, android, adb

I want to use adb commands with use of java. If any one knows how to use then please help me. My required functionality is as below.

1) I want to install one apk using adb command which is i pasted in external storage of SD card.

2) In demo there is one button and on click of that button app will be install that pasted apk in device using **adb install -r APK PATH** this command in java file.

If anyone can help it would be great for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the code below to install application from command line :**

- `adb install example.apk`

  this apk is installed in the internal memory of current opened
  emulator.
- `adb install -s example.apk`

  this apk is installed in the sd-card of current opened emulator.
- `adb -s emulator-5554 install myapp.apk`

  You can also install an apk to specific device in connected device
  list to the adb.

Comment: Yes, That i know but i want to do this using java file in actual device not emulator. You said using command line.

Answer (score 1):

1) you can install app use android packageManger

2) if you still want to use command ,you can try this AndroidUtils 
https://github.com/Blankj/AndroidUtilCode/blob/master/utilcode/README.md
AppUtils, ShellUtils
I hope it can help you

Answer (score 1):

You can basically use Java processs builder
Each ProcessBuilder instance manages a collection of process attributes. It has behaviours to start and waitfor

Just to give you a hint, your code might look some what like this

```
ProcessBuilder apksync = new ProcessBuilder("adb","install","/path_to_apk_file_in_system/filename.apk");
```

You can write a Java code using process builder based on your requirement compile it and run it to get things done.

If you get permission issues

use

```
adb root
```

This restarts the adbd daemon with root permissions and then try executing the commands

Hope this helps

Comment: I used this but it gives me permission denied message in console.

Comment: @SagarKacha use adb root  - restarts the adbd daemon with root permissions

Comment: Can you please guide me more on ABD ROOT commands?. I am on a rooted device and still i need to use ADB ROOT command?

Comment: @SagarKacha thats a different problem, I have no idea about how this reacts in Rooted device. Rooted device is very subjective, each rooted device behave in a very unique way.

Comment: @SagarKacha please post a separate question, about the rooted device. with the rooted device specifications.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for support guys,

Finally got answer and installed apk with command from java.

Here is answer,

We can install application with command in rooted device with using package manager and superuser permission. Here is command for installing application from storage.

```
  String command = "pm install -r " + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/app-debug.apk";
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", command});
  proc.waitFor();
```

Above command is used to install app from Downloads folder.

More Info :  http://cacompadda.com/update-and-install-your-android-app-from-your-own-server-programmatically/

Thanks,
Happy Coding.